# sending raw data through usb on linux

Tags: linux, usb, printing, zebra-printers

I'm printing some labels on a Zebra TLP-2844 printer, and have been doing it fine on Windows by sending the EPL instructions to the shared USB printer as follows:

> type Label.prn > \my-pc\zebra

and it seems to work with serial ports too, with

> type Label.prn > COM1

Now I'm trying to to the same on Linux, but it's getting really hard! My first guess was:

> cat Label.prn | /dev/bus/usb/005/002

since my printer is on bus 005, device 002 (checked it with `lsusb` command) but it doesn't work at all, as I get the following:

> bash: /dev/bus/usb/005/002: Permission denied

Any guesses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you did

```
cat Label.prn | /dev/bus/usb/005/002
```

will try to run `/dev/bus/usb/005/002`, which is not executable, hence "permission denied".
The correct command would be, similar to windows

```
cat Label.prn > /dev/bus/usb/005/002
```

However, not sure if you actually can write anything to a printer like that in linux. If the printer is set up properly, you might also try:

```
lpr Label.prn
```

Comment: didn't work =/
i forgot to mention there are no available drivers to the printer on linux, i'm trying to send this like "raw data" to see what happens!

Comment: I think you must be # root to be able to do that.

Comment: Solved it! It seems to be impossible to send the data directly to the device, but when setting the printer up with CUPS generic text-printer driver and using lpr, it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: On a lexmark laser printer connected to linux, you can actually "cat file > /dev/usb/lp0". The file should be ps, pdf, jpg, html (see docs for natively supported files meaning doesn't require driver).

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else is trying to access raw USB printer ports; The "permission denied" problem is circumvented by adding your user to group "lp", like so:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG lp USERNAME
```

where USERNAME is your username.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry by My english.

I tested here, my printer TLP2844 connect on USB, in my embedded arm9 board with linux.

I typed in command prompt:

printf "OD\r\nN\r\nD5\r\nS2\r\nZT\r\nQ128, 24\r\nq400\r\nA15,10,0,2,1,1,N,\"TESTE\"\r\nP1\r\nFE\r\n" > /dev/lp0

and... the **TEST** printed

Answer (score 3):

1. You should change access mode for /dev/usb/lp0 device: `sudo chmod a+w /dev/usb/lp0`
2. And then you can print a label using copy command: `cp test.zpl /dev/usb/lp0`

Also you can create your own build system in Sublime Text for example:

```
{
    "cmd": ["cp", "$file", "/dev/usb/lp0"],
    "encoding": "utf8"
}
```

and send files to the printer by pressing Ctrl+B keys immediately after finishing edit the label.

Or you can try my tool to send zpl labels to the printer via TCP/IP:
https://github.com/kashamalasha/AutoIt_ZebraTester

It was written on AutoIt Script language, so you need to install AutoIt to build it. Unfortunately there is no description on English, only Russian, but I can write it very soon, if you will need it.